# Cannot get the response data from SPI within embedded Linux

Tags: linux, spi

I'm trying to get some communication with AX58100 by SPI with my MCU.
My Linux kernel is 5.2.
By reference the spidev_test.c from github, https://gist.github.com/priyank/3759616, I can see the slave did have some response after MCU send message after using oscilloscope.
The green line in red part is the data I want.

[image]

And from my test program, I only got below message.

```
root@AX-564EB0MB1T:/home# ./spiTest
spi mode: 0x3
bits per word: 8
max speed: 400000 Hz (400 KHz)
TX | 00 06 08 FF FF __ __ __  |.....|
RX | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........|
TX | 01 06 08 FF FF __ __ __  |.....|
RX | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........|


`// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-only
/*
 * SPI testing utility (using spidev driver)
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2007  MontaVista Software, Inc.
 * Copyright (c) 2007  Anton Vorontsov <avorontsov@ru.mvista.com>
 *
 * Cross-compile with cross-gcc -I/path/to/cross-kernel/include
 */

#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/spi/spidev.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <errno.h>


#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))


static void pabort(const char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    abort();
}

static const char *device = "/dev/spidev9.0";
static uint32_t mode;
static uint8_t bits = 8;
static char *input_file;
static char *output_file;
static uint32_t speed = 400000;
static uint16_t delay;
static int verbose;
static int transfer_size;
static int iterations;
static int interval = 5; /* interval in seconds for showing transfer rate */

uint8_t default_tx[10] = {0};

uint8_t default_rx[ARRAY_SIZE(default_tx)] = {0, };
char *input_tx;

static void hex_dump(const void *src, size_t length, size_t line_size,
             char *prefix)
{
    int i = 0;
    const unsigned char *address = src;
    const unsigned char *line = address;
    unsigned char c;

    printf("%s | ", prefix);
    while (length-- > 0) {
        printf("%02X ", *address++);
        if (!(++i % line_size) || (length == 0 && i % line_size)) {
            if (length == 0) {
                while (i++ % line_size)
                    printf("__ ");
            }
            printf(" |");
            while (line < address) {
                c = *line++;
                printf("%c", (c < 32 || c > 126) ? '.' : c);
            }
            printf("|\n");
            if (length > 0)
                printf("%s | ", prefix);
        }
    }
}


static void transfer(int fd, uint8_t const *tx, uint8_t const *rx, size_t len)
{
    int ret;
    int out_fd;
    struct spi_ioc_transfer tr = {
        .tx_buf = (unsigned long)tx,
        .rx_buf = (unsigned long)rx,
        .len = len,
        .delay_usecs = delay,
        .speed_hz = speed,
        .bits_per_word = bits,
    };

    if (mode & SPI_TX_QUAD)
        tr.tx_nbits = 4;
    else if (mode & SPI_TX_DUAL)
        tr.tx_nbits = 2;
    if (mode & SPI_RX_QUAD)
        tr.rx_nbits = 4;
    else if (mode & SPI_RX_DUAL)
        tr.rx_nbits = 2;
    if (!(mode & SPI_LOOP)) {
        if (mode & (SPI_TX_QUAD | SPI_TX_DUAL))
            tr.rx_buf = 0;
        else if (mode & (SPI_RX_QUAD | SPI_RX_DUAL))
            tr.tx_buf = 0;
    }

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &tr);
    if (ret < 1)
        pabort("can't send spi message");

    //if (verbose)
        hex_dump(tx, len, 8, "TX");

    //if (verbose)
        hex_dump(rx, len+3, 8, "RX");
}

static void print_usage(const char *prog)
{
    printf("Usage: %s [-DsbdlHOLC3vpNR24SI]\n", prog);
    puts("  -D --device   device to use (default /dev/spidev1.1)\n"
         "  -s --speed    max speed (Hz)\n"
         "  -d --delay    delay (usec)\n"
         "  -b --bpw      bits per word\n"
         "  -i --input    input data from a file (e.g. \"test.bin\")\n"
         "  -o --output   output data to a file (e.g. \"results.bin\")\n"
         "  -l --loop     loopback\n"
         "  -H --cpha     clock phase\n"
         "  -O --cpol     clock polarity\n"
         "  -L --lsb      least significant bit first\n"
         "  -C --cs-high  chip select active high\n"
         "  -3 --3wire    SI/SO signals shared\n"
         "  -v --verbose  Verbose (show tx buffer)\n"
         "  -p            Send data (e.g. \"1234\\xde\\xad\")\n"
         "  -N --no-cs    no chip select\n"
         "  -R --ready    slave pulls low to pause\n"
         "  -2 --dual     dual transfer\n"
         "  -4 --quad     quad transfer\n"
         "  -S --size     transfer size\n"
         "  -I --iter     iterations\n");
    exit(1);
}

 static void parse_opts(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    while (1) {
        static const struct option lopts[] = {
            { "device",  1, 0, 'D' },
            { "speed",   1, 0, 's' },
            { "delay",   1, 0, 'd' },
            { "bpw",     1, 0, 'b' },
            { "input",   1, 0, 'i' },
            { "output",  1, 0, 'o' },
            { "loop",    0, 0, 'l' },
            { "cpha",    0, 0, 'H' },
            { "cpol",    0, 0, 'O' },
            { "lsb",     0, 0, 'L' },
            { "cs-high", 0, 0, 'C' },
            { "3wire",   0, 0, '3' },
            { "no-cs",   0, 0, 'N' },
            { "ready",   0, 0, 'R' },
            { "dual",    0, 0, '2' },
            { "verbose", 0, 0, 'v' },
            { "quad",    0, 0, '4' },
            { "size",    1, 0, 'S' },
            { "iter",    1, 0, 'I' },
            { NULL, 0, 0, 0 },
        };
        int c;

        c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "D:s:d:b:i:o:lHOLC3NR24p:vS:I:",
                lopts, NULL);

        if (c == -1)
            break;

        switch (c) {
        case 'D':
            device = optarg;
            break;
        case 's':
            speed = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'd':
            delay = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'b':
            bits = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'i':
            input_file = optarg;
            break;
        case 'o':
            output_file = optarg;
            break;
        case 'l':
            mode |= SPI_LOOP;
            break;
        case 'H':
            mode |= SPI_CPHA;
            break;
        case 'O':
            mode |= SPI_CPOL;
            break;
        case 'L':
            mode |= SPI_LSB_FIRST;
            break;
        case 'C':
            mode |= SPI_CS_HIGH;
            break;
        case '3':
            mode |= SPI_3WIRE;
            break;
        case 'N':
            mode |= SPI_NO_CS;
            break;
        case 'v':
            verbose = 1;
            break;
        case 'R':
            mode |= SPI_READY;
            break;
        case 'p':
            input_tx = optarg;
            break;
        case '2':
            mode |= SPI_TX_DUAL;
            break;
        case '4':
            mode |= SPI_TX_QUAD;
            break;
        case 'S':
            transfer_size = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'I':
            iterations = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        default:
            print_usage(argv[0]);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (mode & SPI_LOOP) {
        if (mode & SPI_TX_DUAL)
            mode |= SPI_RX_DUAL;
        if (mode & SPI_TX_QUAD)
            mode |= SPI_RX_QUAD;
    }
}


static uint64_t _read_count;
static uint64_t _write_count;

/* SPI command definition */
#define HW_SPI_NOP_CMD                     0x00
#define HW_SPI_READ_CMD                    0x02
#define HW_SPI_READ_WITH_WAIT_CMD          0x03
#define HW_SPI_WRITE_CMD                   0x04
#define HW_SPI_ADDR_EXT_CMD                0x06
#define HW_SPI_CMD_MASK                    0x07


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ret = 0;
    int fd;

    parse_opts(argc, argv);

    fd = open(device, O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0)
        pabort("can't open device");

    /*
     * spi mode
     */
    mode = SPI_CPOL | SPI_CPHA;

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MODE32, &mode);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't set spi mode");

    //ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MODE32, &mode);
    //if (ret == -1)
    //  pabort("can't get spi mode");

    /*
     * bits per word
     */
    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't set bits per word");

    //ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits);
    //if (ret == -1)
    //  pabort("can't get bits per word");

    /*
     * max speed hz
     */
    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &speed);
    if (ret == -1)
    pabort("can't set max speed hz");

    //ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &speed);
    //if (ret == -1)
    //  pabort("can't get max speed hz");

    printf("spi mode: 0x%x\n", mode);
    printf("bits per word: %d\n", bits);
    printf("max speed: %d Hz (%d KHz)\n", speed, speed/1000);

    //addr=0x0000 type
    memset(default_tx, 0, sizeof(default_tx));
    default_tx[0] = 0x00;
    default_tx[1] = 0x00 | HW_SPI_ADDR_EXT_CMD;
    default_tx[2] = (0x00 & 0xe0) | (HW_SPI_READ_CMD << 2);
    default_tx[3] = 0xFF;//dummy
    default_tx[3+1] = 0x0;//data
    default_tx[3+1] = 0xFF;//data
    //default_tx[5] = 0xFF;
    transfer(fd, default_tx, default_rx, 5);//sizeof(default_tx));

    //addr=0x0001 version
    memset(default_tx, 0, sizeof(default_tx));
    default_tx[0] = 0x01;
    default_tx[1] = 0x00 | HW_SPI_ADDR_EXT_CMD;
    default_tx[2] = (0x01 & 0xe0) | (HW_SPI_READ_CMD << 2);
    default_tx[3] = 0xFF;//dummy
    default_tx[3+1] = 0x0;//data
    default_tx[3+1] = 0xFF;//data
    //default_tx[5] = 0xFF;
    transfer(fd, default_tx, default_rx, 5);//sizeof(default_tx));

    close(fd);

    return ret;
}`
```

I know there are some different mode of SPI, but I'm a new one of it.
From the pic, it seems this is write and read at the same time.
I'm not sure exactly.

Is there any one can tell that how I can modify my SPI setting to get the response data?

Thanks.
Eric